# Retrieve the UID of the NFC chip on an Android device NOT tag

Tags: android, nfc

I was wondering if it is possible to receive the UID of an NFC CHIP of the android device where the app is installed? I tried retrieving using `NfcAdapter` But unfortunately without luck.

Comment: Share what things you tried

Comment: The NFC reader hardware does not have a UID, If a Android device is doing Host Card Emulation, then if it is emulating a Card that has a UID you would read it just like you read a Card of the type it is emulating. Also not all device to device NFC uses Host Card Emulation, and these protocols also don't have UID